# Changing another DIVs css property on hover not working

Tags: css

I am having an issue where I cannot get another div to change a css property on hover.

My HTML structure is as follows:

```
<section class="grid panel-small">
  <div class="col-6 grid-container">
    <div class="col-12 item">
        <a href="#" class="item-area gold">
           <div class="full-row" style="
               background-image: url(https://www.painterartist.com/static/ptr/product_content/painter/2018/bob-ross/gallery/03.jpg)">
           </div>
           <div class="item-description">
                 <div class="item-description-inner">
                     <h2>Title</h2>
                     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec faucibus sed sem eget efficitur.</p>
                     <div class="feature-btn">
                         View more
                            <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
                      </div>
                </div>
           </div>
        </a>
     </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

I want to be able to change `item-description-inner` to have a positive margin rather than a negative one.

Here is my CSS:

```
  main#container .grid, main#container .grid .grid-container {
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: flex;
     -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
     flex-flow: row wrap;
  }

   main#container .grid .grid-container .item {
      -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
      flex: 1 auto;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
   }

    main#container .grid .grid-container .item > .item-area {
         position: relative;
         width: 100%;
         display: block;
         z-index: 1
      }

    main#container .grid .grid-container .item > .item-area > .full-row {
            padding-bottom: 56.222%;
         }

    main#container .grid .grid-container .item > .item-area > .half-row {
        padding-bottom: 112%;
        padding-bottom: calc( 2 * 56.222%);
     }

     main#container .grid .grid-container .item > .item-area .item-description {
        padding-right: 55px;
        padding-bottom: 33px;
        padding-left: 55px;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
     }

        main#container .grid .grid-container .item > .item-area .item-description > .item-description-inner {
           margin-top: -31px;
           margin-bottom: 31px;
        }

.item > .item-area:hover .item-description > .item-description-inner {
    margin-top: 31px;
}
```

I read this [S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered) article, and read about `~` and `+` but none of these selectors are working for me.

Comment: add more specifity, make it the same as the above one and add the hover

Comment: Can you try `.item > .item-area:hover .item-description > .item-description-inner`? Might be that the browser decides that the first rule is more specific than the hover rule. So even though the rule is applied, the normal rule overrides it.

Comment: Or preferably add less specificity to the first

Comment: above comments are right. If you want more details you can read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @MalteHartwig thanks. This has not worked for me however.

Comment: maybe there is more CSS that we need to see ... maybe the `a` has a height  = 0 for some reason

Comment: @TemaniAfif I have added more of my code. Sorry.

Comment: it's working fine for me ... just create a snippet and tested

Comment: @TemaniAfif It doesn't for me https://jsfiddle.net/mucjnajg/1/

Comment: as we said specificity issue :) add this `.grid .grid-container` to the last selector ... you need to make it similar to the other one + the hover

Comment: @TemaniAfif many thanks indeed! P.s. Answer the question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing a specificity issue as the intial selector is more specific than the one with the hover

---

This one is more specific:

```
 main#container .grid .grid-container .item > .item-area .item-description > .item-description-inner
```

Than this one:

```
.item > .item-area:hover .item-description > .item-description-inner
```

To fix the issue you can add more specifity to the second one and make it like this :

```
main#container .grid .grid-container .item > .item-area:hover .item-description > .item-description-inner
```

*You can also make the first one less specific*

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
.item-description-inner {
                margin-top: -31px;
                margin-bottom: 31px;
}

.item-description-inner:hover {
                 margin-top: 31px;
}
```